# Re-enabling Wireless Network Controller in Debian 10

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I'm working on a debian machine which has it's wireless access disabled. Sometime in the past I followed a guide (which I can't find) about permanently disabling wifi in linux. I'm trying to determine what is blocking the interface and how to re-enable it.

Things I've checked so far:

**BIOS** -
The wireless device is recognized and enabled, which is good.

**Desktop** - No options visible for wifi, only wired connections.

**ifconfig** - returns enp3s0 (Ethernet) and loopback, no wlan.

**nmcli dev status** - shows the same interfaces as ifconfig

**iwconfig** - lists the same results, "no wireless extentions"

**modeprobe.d** looks empty

**rfkill** isn't blocking anything

**nmcli radio** - returns wifi is enabled

When listing all pci devices with **lspci** I see both Ethernet and the wireless Network controller.

I think the way I disabled wifi in  the first place was by placing some lines in a bash script, but can't remember if this is called on startup or if I runned it once.

How should I troubleshoot this? Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Try:   (1)  sudo ifconfig wlan0 down ; sudo ifconfig wlan0 up to see if that works. Then (2) shut down, remove the wireless adapter, start up without it, shut down, install the wireless adapter, start up and configure it.  I think it reasonable that one or both of these two should work.

Comment: I wonder if the wifi module has been blacklisted.  Check /etc/moduled.conf and /etc/modules-load.d/* for any blacklist lines.

Comment: To test if its module related find the appropriate module related to the lspci entry, insmod it and see if the interface starts to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the responses, upon checking the modules I noticed there was something very wrong with the drivers and the only way was to completely remove them and install again the drivers recommended for that specific interface.

I successfully restored wifi after reading https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi
and following the appropriate instructions for my chipset.
For anyone having trouble getting their wireless interfaces up please check the debian's wiki link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).